# Memory leaks, and strange bugs with runnable class - How to properly dispose of objects?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, memory-leaks, runnable

I was building a server application to track how many people are currently running another application I was recently building. This was more just to test myself and see what I can do with the language, and in almost no time I was able to get things working. However, I ran into a serious issue when running artificial tests on the application. Ill post my code...

Main class:

```
public class ServerGUIStatistics {

public static MainWindow mw = null;
private static int _port = 33672;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    mw = new MainWindow();
    new ServerGUIStatistics();
}

public ServerGUIStatistics(){
    ServerSocket listener = null;
    try{
        listener = new ServerSocket(_port, 100);
        while(true){
           System.out.println("Waiting for connection....");
           Socket connection = listener.accept(); 
           Connection nc = new Connection(connection);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        mw.setConsoleOutput(ex.getMessage(), 2);// Prints to a console output window...
    }
}
```

And the burnable class which I think is causing the issues.

```
class Connection implements Runnable {
private static int _totalConnections = 0;
private static long _totalConnectionsAllTime = 0;
private Socket socket = null;
private boolean stopFlag = true;

@Override
public void run(){
    while(stopFlag){
        stopFlag = false;
        ServerGUIStatistics.mw.setConsoleOutput("New connection from \"" + socket.getInetAddress().toString() + "\" on port " + socket.getPort(), 0);// Prints to a console output window... 
        ServerGUIStatistics.mw.updateConNumber(_totalConnections);
        ServerGUIStatistics.mw.updateConAllTimeNumber(_totalConnectionsAllTime);//Updates a field on the main window which displays the total number of users connected
        boolean stayAlive = true;
        try{
            socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
            BufferedInputStream connectionStatus = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            do{
                int holder = connectionStatus.read();
                switch(holder){
                    case 1:
                        stayAlive = true;
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        stayAlive = false;
                        break;
                } 
            }
            while(stayAlive);
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            ServerGUIStatistics.mw.setConsoleOutput(socket.getInetAddress().toString() + " " + ex.getMessage(), 2); // Prints to a console output window...
        }
        _totalConnections--;
        ServerGUIStatistics.mw.updateConNumber(_totalConnections); //Updates a field on the main window which displays the current number of users connected
        return;
    }
}

Connection(Socket soc){
    socket = soc;
    _totalConnections++;
    _totalConnectionsAllTime++;
    new Thread(this).start();
}

public static int getTotalConnections(){
    return _totalConnections;
}
```

Here is the swing window (Generated by netbeans) :

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.*;

public class MainWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form MainWindow
 */
private Date curDate = null;
private SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("MM/dd/yyyy @ hh:mm:ss");

public MainWindow() {
    initComponents();
    this.setVisible(true);
}
/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {
    bindingGroup = new org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup();

    jTabbedPane1 = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    totalConnectionsOut = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    totalConnectionsAllTimeOut = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    consoleOutput = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    totalConnectionsOut.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 58)); // NOI18N
    totalConnectionsOut.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);
    totalConnectionsOut.setText("0");

    org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, totalConnectionsOut, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("false"), totalConnectionsOut, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("editable"));
    bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

    totalConnectionsAllTimeOut.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 58)); // NOI18N
    totalConnectionsAllTimeOut.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);
    totalConnectionsAllTimeOut.setText("0");

    binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, totalConnectionsAllTimeOut, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("false"), totalConnectionsAllTimeOut, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("editable"));
    bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

    jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel1.setText("Total Connections:");

    jLabel2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel2.setText("Total Current Connections:");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(totalConnectionsOut)
                .addComponent(totalConnectionsAllTimeOut, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 571, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(4, 4, 4)
            .addComponent(totalConnectionsOut, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 150, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 34, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(totalConnectionsAllTimeOut, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 150, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    jTabbedPane1.addTab("Info", jPanel1);

    consoleOutput.setColumns(20);
    consoleOutput.setRows(5);

    binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, consoleOutput, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("false"), consoleOutput, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("editable"));
    bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(consoleOutput);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
    jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
    jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 571, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 368, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    jTabbedPane1.addTab("Console Output", jPanel3);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jTabbedPane1)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jTabbedPane1)
    );

    bindingGroup.bind();

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

public void setConsoleOutput(String s, int i){
    String type = null;
    switch(i){
        case 0:
            type = "Info";
            break;
        case 1:
            type = "Error";
            break;
        case 2:
            type = "Exception";
            break;
        default:
            type = "Unknown";
            break;
    }
    curDate = new Date();
    String output = consoleOutput.getText() + "[" + ft.format(curDate) + "][" + type + "] " + s + "\n";
    consoleOutput.setText(output);
}

public void updateConNumber(int i){
    totalConnectionsOut.setText(Integer.toString(i));
}

public void updateConAllTimeNumber(long i){
    totalConnectionsAllTimeOut.setText(Long.toString(i));
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JTextArea consoleOutput;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextField totalConnectionsAllTimeOut;
private javax.swing.JTextField totalConnectionsOut;
private org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup bindingGroup;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

If anything looks strange, or is incorrect then I remind you that Im still fairly new with Java and am new to making these sorts of applications.

Here is the artificial test I made:

```
class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        while(true){
            try{
                Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 33672);
                BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                    out.write(1);
                    out.flush();
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                }

                out.write(0);
                out.flush();

                out.close();
                socket.close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex){System.out.println(ex);}
            System.out.println("Finished! Running again...");
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, it rapidly connects to create new threads, exchanges a few messages, and then disconnects then repeats. I left this running until it had run its cycle around 1500 times, which it got through in no time at all. But seemingly out of no where my memory usage started to climb... Like, a lot. So much that it started to freeze my computer up. As i said before, it got to 1500 cycles without issue. Around then it was using 80 to 100 megabytes of memory, but after that it started to climb slowly. And by 2500 cycles it was using a little over 1GB of memory. And by 5000 it had saturated nearly all my systems memory.

Now, I believe the way I would fix this is to set instances of the Connection class equal to null when I was finished with them. But I'm not sure how to go about doing that with how the program is set up.

Is there a way to set an object to null from within itself, or is there another way to go about doing this that I should be using?

Comment: The GC should take care of objects once they are out of scope, but not resources. Where do you close your connectionStatus stream as I don't see this being done any where?  Perhaps you want to use try-with resources? Also, it may be a minor issue, but consider using a fixed size thread pool for your threads.

Comment: Fixed size thread pool... What do you mean by that? Sorry Im as green as can be. Is there some sort of video/lesson you can send me to which will explain?

Comment: I must be off to bed, and Google is your friend. Good luck to you.

Comment: Have you tried closing the `Socket` before you exit `Connection`.  Also, you're violating the single thread rules of Swing.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: Short lived objects can cause some issues between GC cycles.  I added code to close and nullify the `Socket` and then comment out the functionality of the `setConsoleOutput` and profiled the code using `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and the used heap space never exceeded 10mb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So things that jump out at me...

In the following code...

```
while(stopFlag){
    stopFlag = false;
    ServerGUIStatistics.mw.setConsoleOutput("New connection from \"" + socket.getInetAddress().toString() + "\" on port " + socket.getPort(), 0);// Prints to a console output window... 
    ServerGUIStatistics.mw.updateConNumber(_totalConnections);
    ServerGUIStatistics.mw.updateConAllTimeNumber(_totalConnectionsAllTime);//Updates a field on the main window which displays the total number of users connected
    boolean stayAlive = true;
    try{
        socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
        BufferedInputStream connectionStatus = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        do{
            int holder = connectionStatus.read();
            switch(holder){
                case 1:
                    stayAlive = true;
                    break;
                case 0:
                    stayAlive = false;
                    break;
            } 
        }
        while(stayAlive);
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        ServerGUIStatistics.mw.setConsoleOutput(socket.getInetAddress().toString() + " " + ex.getMessage(), 2); // Prints to a console output window...
    }
    _totalConnections--;
    ServerGUIStatistics.mw.updateConNumber(_totalConnections); //Updates a field on the main window which displays the current number of users connected
    return;
}
```

- The outer (`while (stopFlag)`) makes no sense, as you never test for it while reading from the inner loop and once you exit the inner loop, you call `return`
- You never close the `BufferedInputStream` or the `Socket`.  Either of these two could be maintaining a strong reference to resources which are no longer been used, preventing the class from getting garbage collected

A better solution "might" look something like...

```
ServerGUIStatistics.mw.setConsoleOutput("New connection from \"" + socket.getInetAddress().toString() + "\" on port " + socket.getPort(), 0);// Prints to a console output window... 
ServerGUIStatistics.mw.updateConNumber(_totalConnections);
ServerGUIStatistics.mw.updateConAllTimeNumber(_totalConnectionsAllTime);//Updates a field on the main window which displays the total number of users connected
boolean stayAlive = true;
try {
    socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
    try (BufferedInputStream connectionStatus = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream())) {
        do {
            System.out.println(number + " reading...");
            int holder = connectionStatus.read();
            System.out.println(number + " read " + holder + "...");
            switch (holder) {
                case 1:
                    stayAlive = true;
                    break;
                case 0:
                    stayAlive = false;
                    break;
            }
        } while (stayAlive);
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ServerGUIStatistics.mw.setConsoleOutput(socket.getInetAddress().toString() + " " + ex.getMessage(), 2); // Prints to a console output window...
} finally {
    System.out.println(number + " exiting");
    _totalConnections--;
    try {
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    socket = null;
    ServerGUIStatistics.mw.updateConNumber(_totalConnections); //Updates a field on the main window which displays the current number of users connected
}
```

Note the use of [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to ensure that the `BufferedInputStream` is closed when the code exists the `try` block.

Note the use of `finally` to ensure that the code block is executed regardless of how the `try` block is exited.  This guarantees that the code is executed.

Next, I turned my focus to ...

```
public void setConsoleOutput(String s, int i){
    String type = null;
    switch(i){
        case 0:
            type = "Info";
            break;
        case 1:
            type = "Error";
            break;
        case 2:
            type = "Exception";
            break;
        default:
            type = "Unknown";
            break;
    }
    curDate = new Date();
    String output = consoleOutput.getText() + "[" + ft.format(curDate) + "][" + type + "] " + s + "\n";
    consoleOutput.setText(output);
}
```

Ignoring your violation of the single threads of Swing for a moment, the immediate problem is you're creating a new `Date` object on each run of this method, which is called 1000's of times, but the `Date` object itself is an instance field which could just add to the issues.

But what was of real concern was this...

```
String output = consoleOutput.getText() + "[" + ft.format(curDate) + "][" + type + "] " + s + "\n";
```

While the compiler does a good job of optimization, the `consoleOutput.getText()` method will create a new `String` with the contents of the text area, which you then use to apply back to the `JTextArea` using `setText`

This is woefully inefficient, as the underlying `Document` is converting it's `char` array to a `String` and the `String` back to a `char` array each time...

Instead, you can solve both problems relatively simply...

```
public void setConsoleOutput(String s, int i) {
    String type = null;
    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            type = "Info";
            break;
        case 1:
            type = "Error";
            break;
        case 2:
            type = "Exception";
            break;
        default:
            type = "Unknown";
            break;
    }
    String output = "[" + ft.format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "][" + type + "] " + s + "\n";
    consoleOutput.append(output);
}
```

Instead of creating a new `Date` object, simply use `System.currentTimeMillis()` and pass this to the `SimpleDateFormatter`.  Next, simply use `append` to append the text to the end of the `JTextArea`, this will reduce the number of temporary objects been created by at least one, if not more, reducing the overhead of a GC cycle and not leaving a bunch of short lived objects piling up in the heap...

I ran this updated code through a profiler (in Netbeans) using `Integer.MAX_VALUE` as the loop terminator and didn't see the used heap size pass 10mb until about the 4000th cycle or so...

Now, because of the nature of the `JTextArea`, I would expect to see a slight increase of memory usage over time, as it needs to keep all the text in memory (and the associated overhead of calculating the text layout)

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details about Swing and threads

Comment: Im right about to run out to the store (Ill read the rest of what you wrote when i come back) but i just want to point out before I go that "(while (stopFlag))" was most likely added as an experiment when the program was in a different form which I forgot to remove.

Comment: Thank you very much :) This was beyond helpful, Ill be sure to take all of this into account while i continue to make this server application!